# Chat GPT OpenAI API key security issue

Tags: ios, security, https, openai-api

I have used chat GPT open AI API in `iOS application`, their https API requires Authorization key in headers with API key.

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
-d '{"model": "text-davinci-003", "prompt": "Say this is a test", "temperature": 0, "max_tokens": 7}'
```

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/making-requests

I have tried using sniffer app "Http Checker" to check if the API key can be sniffed and it is easily decoded.

[image: You can see in the image that anyone can easily get/sniff API key]

What can be the solution to avoid this API key to be exposed?
As their api document clearly says

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
```

So, anyone using the iOS app can sniff and use the API_KEY

There are multiple other ways to move the open ai API to cloud function, custom server, etc but if anyone integrating the API directly in Mobile application,
Is there a way that this API_KEY cannot be accessed directly using third party apps?

Comment: I found a ChatGPT SDK for IOS.
It is well-documented, easy to setup up, less complex, and seamlessly integrates with the IOS environment.
You can try it out here : https://ttps://github.com/DevCrew-io/chatgpt-ios-sdk

Answer (score 3):

Well, the credentials are transferred via HTTPS. As such not everyone can sniff it, but only people who have access to the unencrypted HTTP data. This is *exactly* what https is supposed to protect against.

You are only able to "sniff" the data because you are deliberately opening up the connection by using a proxy server or similar and trusting their TLS invalid certificate.

Comment: Is there anyway that headers are not exposed? Any person can use third party services and get the required API_Key and use it. The API key has pricing, so anyone take advantage of accessing it :(

Comment: Yes, by using HTTPS. Which you already are.

Comment: I am already using HTTPS but third party tool exposed the headers, i don't want the headers to be exposed

Comment: The third party tool "exposed" the headers specifically because you allowed this tool to read the data. With normal validation rules, i.e. with the client enforcing a valid server certificate, the data is only accessible to the client and the server, but no man-in-the-middle. If this is still a concern however, please edit your original question and add more details about (1) the "sniffer" tool you are using and (2) how you have configured it to access the in-transit request. As you are running a `curl` command and your screenshot showing an iOS app, this seems like an uncommon setup.

Comment: As stated by others HTTPS will encrypt the headers, no other user will be able to use a tool like 'sniffer' to access the API key.

Comment: @HolgerJust, i have edited the question with more details, any help will be appreciated

Comment: @KaneHooper Reading the thread, maybe I've got you wrong here guys, but I cannot understand the whole https encryption argument. What prevents another guy from using the same sniff software to read all the headers? It's as easy as to install Charles or Proxyman or Wireshark

Answer (score 2):

One would just have to install an app like „Proxyman“ or any of the alternatives and allow https sniffing for this domain and then can easily see the decrypted https response. ssl pinning, like Holger suggested, is not an option here since we would need to know the privat key of openai servers if I’m not mistaken. You would have to have your own intermediate backend that does some encryption on top.

I too would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Pinning does not require the private key; only the public key, and can absolutely be applied to a server you don't control. But I agree that the better solution is an intermediate backend. This gives you dramatically more control. Even if you can prevent sniffing, it's possible to pull the key from the binary.

Comment: I have added custom backend and encrypted the API key.